# getting MODULE FAILURE error with pipelining = True in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am getting the following error when running my Ansible playbook:

> {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "setup"}, "module_stderr": "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

I have ssh pipelining = `True` in my `ansible.cfg` and if I make it `false` the error message goes away.

I am trying this on CentOS 7 machine and my Ansible version is 2.1.1.0. Is there any way I can get rid of above error without turning off the ssh pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with these changes in my playbook:

```
   vars:
    ansible_ssh_pipelining: no
   tasks:
    - name: Disable require tty access in /etc/sudoers
      replace: dest="/etc/sudoers"
               regexp='^Defaults    requiretty'
               replace='Defaults    !requiretty'
```